# My cronjobs are displaying in PuTTy, but have disappeared from cPanel

Tags: cron, cpanel, whm

My crons are still running, but I can no longer display them from cPanel. It appears some permissions have changed or something preventing cPanel to view them.

They are still there and still running, I just can't see the list of them from cPanel.

Any ideas what file or file permissions might have changed to have them disappear from my cPanel view?

Edit:  After evaluating further, I see all my crons are still visible at /var/spool/cron and are still running.  I have ran "chmod 4775 /usr/bin/crontab" and still no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update your cPanel with following command

```
/scripts/upcp --force
```

Comment: Upgrade completed at 100% and no updates to my cron jobs.  Any help really is appreciated as none of my cPanel accounts can create/edit/view cron jobs.

Comment: I just resolved the viewing portion of this.  My cron.deny file was set to 600.  I updated permissions to 644 and my Current Cron Jobs are displaying again.  I am not able to edit or view, but my error has been changed.  I will continue working on my permissions to see what was changed.

Comment: Not all things are solved in WHM/Cpanel with /scripts/upcp. Before there are many things to do, like watching cpanel logs, analyze the system logs. On thi case, /var/log/cron and /var/log/messages it's more efective that spend time with upcp --force